# Efficient Simulation of Brownian Motion in R

Tags: r

```
data=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000*300,0,1),1000,300))
weiner.matrix=data.frame(cumsum(data))

mu=0
sigma=.15
dt=1/1000


 bmot=data.frame(matrix(NA,1000,300)
    bmot[1,]=100
    for (j in 1:ncol(data)){
    for (i in 2:nrow(data)){

      bmot[i,j]=bmot[i-1,j]*(1+mu*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*(weiner.matrix[i,j]-weiner.matrix[i-1,j]))

    }
    }
```

I am trying to simulate a matrix of 1000 rows and 300 columns, so 300 variables really of geometric Brownian motion. Initial value starts at a 100 and then randomness kicks in periods after t=1/row=1.

Is there a way to run this 300 brownian motion simulation without going cell-by-cell as I have in the loop??

Comment: What are `weiner.matrix`, `mu`, `dt`, `sigma`...? Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` on a set of normal variables to produce a single variable of brownian motion.

```
random <- rnorm(1000, 0, sqrt(0.15))
x <- 100 + cumsum(random)
nsim <- 300
```

You can use apply, but a `for` loop is just as fast:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(n = nsim * 1000, sd = sqrt(0.15)), nrow = 1000, ncol = 300)
for (i in 1:nsim) X[,i] <- cumsum(X[,i])
```